# Is it possible to upload logos for an Alexa Skill using the ASK CLI?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, ask-cli

I'm learning how I might manage multiple similar Alexa Skills at scale.  I think I have an approach to create and update the skills using gulp-template and the ask-cli.

However, I can't find a way to programmatically upload logos for the skills.  Is this possible via the ask cli, or must I upload them manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ask cli, publishing related information will be present in the skill-package/skill.json file. Update the "publishingInformation" section per locale with new logos. Reference:[documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/skill-manifest.html#locales)

Use "deploy" command to update the skill.

Comment: Ah, I've only ever downloaded the skill file which contains a reference to an s3 file that I'd uploaded via the Alexa console.  You're proposing I edit the skill file to reference a local file that I then deploy via the "deploy" command.  Makes sense, thanks